# Specific URLs fail with one ISP

Tags: home-networking

I have home DSL and Cable service with two different providers. Both connections are live, and quick enough (the slower one gives us 20MBPS/5MBPS up). Both connections allow us to use the internet normally (streaming, zoom calls, etc).

My employer's URLs produce Server Not Found errors when loaded with the DSL connection, but load successfully with the cable connection. `downforeveryoneorjustme.com` shows the site is up and working. Occasionally, the DSL connection will be able to find the URL successfully for a few minutes before it breaks again. Other pages have no issues.

I have confirmed this behavior across devices (mobile and desktop), and across browsers (chromium, firefox). when I connect to a VPN using the impacted connection, the URL loads as expected. Technical support from the failing ISP tells me that there are no firewalls associated with their hardware or service, including the modem/router we rent from them.

What could be causing this behavior? Where would I begin troubleshooting?

Comment: Is it different DNS on each? Can you connect by IP address?

Comment: Or manually set a probably-better DNS like 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 or 4.2.2.1 ? @stark: some things like VPN and SSH should work by address without DNS, but HTTP 1.1+ usually won't due to Host header and HTTPS always won't due to certificate

Answer (score 0):

In this case, my ISP's DNS server had blacklisted my employer's website. (They claim that .edu domains are frequently blacklisted by their bots.) They were able to resolve the issue, but were only willing to do so once they were convinced the issue was, indeed, their responsibility.

Key indicators that the issue was ISP-specific were:

- I happen to have service with two ISPs, and one connects successfully
- I am able to connect to the web site through a VPN, on the impacted ISP's connection, indicating that this is not an issue with the site, but rather with the local network.

@Stark's recommendation to connect directly to the IP address will allow you to confirm whether a failure in the DNS lookup process is causing the issue.
`ping some_website.com` will return an IP address for `some_website.com`. The troubleshooting steps above were enough to convince ISP support staff to look into and correct the issue.